Luke 15:32 (Prodigal Son last verse) - Verb tenses
All major Greek manuscript traditions read the same ending of Luke 15:32

ἀπολωλὼς ἦν καὶ εὑρέθη

All major English translations (and even two major interlinears) similarly render this:

was lost, and is found.

However, when I read the Greek (as a noob), I read

ἀπολωλὼς(was lost/destoryed) ἦν(was) καὶ(and) εὑρέθη(was found)

Am I right in reading everything as past tense?
From what I can tell εὑρέθη is a "Verb Aorist Passive Indicative 3rd Singular," which describes an action that was done to a noun being discussed, i.e., "he(subject) was found."

Greek Manuscripts
First, there is a minor dispute between the NA28/UBS5 text vs the Byzantine texts for Luke 15:32 -

NA28/UBS5: νεκρὸς ἦν καὶ ἔζησεν, καὶ ἀπολωλὼς καὶ εὑρέθη = was dead, and enlivened, and lost and found
Byzantine Text: νεκρὸς ἦν, καὶ ἀνέζησεν· καὶ ἀπολωλὼς ἦν, καὶ εὑρέθη = was dead made alive, and was lost and found

Note that these differences are scarcely translatable and have no material impact on the meaning.
Verb Tenses
English does not have an aorist tense, and so the very subtle differences between aorist tenses and simple past tense are almost impossible to render into English. In practical terms, such a difference is rarely even important. The usual practice is to translate the Greek aorist tense into the simple past tense, as in both languages. This does not say whether the action is complete (i.e., "perfect") or ongoing (i.e., "imperfect") as per the aorist.
In any case, at the moment the father in the parable speaks, all the events he is describing are in the past: the son that was lost and has been found.

Yes, "is found" sounds like the meaning of a perfect tense more than aorist.  However, Wallace has this verse listed as an example of an ingressive aorist, stressing "the beginning of an action or the entrance into a state." The translators used "is found" to fit the context.

The aorist tense may be used to stress the beginning of an action or the entrance into a state. Unlike the ingressive imperfect, there is no implication that the action continues. This is simply left unstated. The ingressive aorist is quite common.
--
Wallace, D. B. (1996). Greek Grammar beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament (p. 558). Zondervan.

